# Innok Heros simulation with ROS Kinetic and Gazebo

Tags: ros, tutorial, ros-kinetic, package, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

does everyone know, how to simulate the Innok Heros with ROS Kinetic.
The tutorial is just for Indigo. http://wiki.ros.org/innok_heros_gazebo/Tutorials/Simulating%20Innok%20Heros

What are the names of the kinetic-packages?

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288532/innok-heros-simulation-with-ros-kinetic-and-gazebo/) by [ich4913](https://answers.ros.org/users/34627/ich4913/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-04-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

you can get the required packages from github using the branch 'kinetic':

- https://github.com/innokrobotics/innok_heros_gazebo
- https://github.com/innokrobotics/innok_heros_description
- https://github.com/innokrobotics/innok_heros_control

Usage is just the same as described in the tutorial for Indigo.

Regards,

Sabrina

---

Originally posted by [Sabrina](https://answers.ros.org/users/307/sabrina/) with karma: 285 on 2018-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0